# fullcalendar removeEventSource not working when event source is object property

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/4G75c/

If you take a look at the above fiddle I add/remove multiple event sources using buttons.

removeEventSource method is not working and repeated clicks of the toggle buttons cause duplicate event sources to be added.

I have read the docs which explains having the same object reference.
Can anyone shed any light on this?

```
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(this.types[target.data('type')].active){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', this.types[target.data('type')].events);
    }else{
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.types[target.data('type')].events);
    }
```

Comment: FullCalendar 1.6.4 - working example http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/4G75c/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 2.0.2 (current as of this reply) the issue appears to be related to the way event sources are added; if you examine the code, the *buildEventSource* function, which is called from within *addEventSource*, converts the source data before adding it to the calendar. The *removeEventSource* function does not reverse the conversion and, as a result, there is no match found and the event source is not removed.

I reported a related bug two weeks ago but it still has not been accepted. Basically, your options are to dig into the code yourself and develop a workaround, or wait for a release that addresses the issue. I have incorporated a workaround for my specific situation but it is not universal; if the bug isn't accepted within the following week I will incorporate a more permanent (and universal) fix.

Comment: Thanks I figured so. I've opted to wait for a fix in new version. v2.0.0 does not have the bug so am using that for now.