# How to compare two elements' attribute value and modify its element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare two elements'attribute value and then modify the attribute? For example, I have a photos of a selection of chairs: red, green, black etc etc and they are ranked by "data-slick-index". when a color is selected, say red, I want to compare the photos's "color-option" attribute, if they match with the selected color (red in this case), I want to deleted the "data-slick-index" attribute of the ones that are not red so they will not show up in thumbnail.

```
<div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 3180px; transform: translate3d(-1680px, 0px, 0px);">
   <li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item slick-slide slick-cloned" color-option="Army Green" data-slick-index="-4" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 60px; display: none; clear: none;">
   <li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item slick-slide slick-cloned" color-option="Army Green" data-slick-index="-3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 60px; display: none; clear: none;">
   <li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item slick-slide" color-option="Candy Red" data-slick-index="34" aria-hidden="true" role="option" tabindex="-1" style="width: 60px; display: none; clear: none;">
   <li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item slick-slide" color-option="Candy Red" data-slick-index="33" aria-hidden="true" role="option" tabindex="-1" style="width: 60px; display: none; clear: none;">
   <li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item slick-slide" color-option="Navy Blue" data-slick-index="11" aria-hidden="true" role="option" tabindex="-1" style="width: 60px; display: none; clear: none;">
   <li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item slick-slide" color-option="Navy Blue" data-slick-index="10" aria-hidden="true" role="option" tabindex="-1" style="width: 60px; display: none; clear: none;">
```

What I have now is this:

```
$(function() {
  $('li.product-single__thumbnails-item').each(function(){
 var $ColorOfEach = $(this).attr('color-option');
  var $GetSelectedElement = document.getElementById("FeaturedImage-product-template");
  var $SelectedColor = $GetSelectedElement.getAttribute("color-option");


    if ($ColorOfEach != $SelectedColor) { 
     $(this).removeAttribute('data-slick-index');
} 
});
 });
```

I dont think it is right because I am removing the attribute from an attribute, not from the actual Li element, can anyone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle?

Comment: it looks like $(this) is refering to the <li>

Comment: $mobilemodelselected where it is came from ?

Comment: @JYoThI Sorry, it was a mistake, it is corrected now, it is supposed to be GetSelectedElement, would you mind checking again? Thanks!

Comment: @ScotNery: really?Sorry, I am a total noobie, I dont know why but the "data-slick-index" attribute is still there, this is what I got from the console tool:
theme.js:2898 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeAttribute is not a function
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (theme.js:2898)
    at Function.each (vendor.js:13)
    at re.fn.init.each (vendor.js:13)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (theme.js:2891)
    at u (vendor.js:14)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (vendor.js:14)
    at ready (vendor.js:14)

Comment: your mixing javascript function with jquery function change like this  removeAttr()  @jcyu215

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fullcalendar removeEventSource not working when event source is object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829248/fullcalendar-removeeventsource-not-working-when-event-source-is-object-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Replace removeAttribute with removeAttr because its JavaScript
  function and you are using jQuery function
- 2nd your HTML also incorrect Li tag always under UL element

```js
$(function() {
  $('li.product-single__thumbnails-item').each(function() {
    var $ColorOfEach = $(this).attr('color-option');
    var $GetSelectedElement = document.getElementById("FeaturedImage-product-template");
    var $SelectedColor = $mobilemodelselected.getAttribute("color-option");
    if ($ColorOfEach != $SelectedColor) {
      $(this).removeAttr('data-slick-index');
    }
  });
});
```